# thread 'main' panicked at 'Error Reading public.asc EOF' (Rust)

Tags: rust, pgp

I'm trying to decode a PGP public key using the sequoia_openpgp crate but I get this error

```
'Error: Custom { kind: UnexpectedEof, error: FileError { path: "public.asc", source: Custom { kind: UnexpectedEof, error: "EOF" } } }'
```

```
use openpgp::armor::{Kind, Reader, ReaderMode};

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let mut file = File::open("public.asc")?;
    let mut reader = Reader::from_reader(&mut file, ReaderMode::Tolerant(Some(Kind::File)));
    let mut data = String::new();
    match reader.read_to_string(&mut data) {
        Err(why) => panic!("Error: {:?}", why),
        Ok(_) => print!("contains:\n\n{}", data),
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Your error suggests the file 'public.asc' is corrupted. Without further details (i.e. a [minimal reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) in your specific case the 'public.asc' we can't really help you.

Comment: @cafce25 the file is a pgp public key. I tried other methods and it works fine but not with Reader